# Estimating the uncertainty on the difference of two random variables

Tags: missing-data, uncertainty

Let $(X_0, X_1)$ a pair of (non-independent) random variables and $Z\in\{0,1\}$ a Bernoulli random variable, independent from $(X_0,X_1)$. Let $\Delta = X_1 - X_0$. We're interested in the distribution of $\Delta$.

Consider $(X_{0,i}, X_{1,i}, Z_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ i.i.d. copies of these random variables and $\Delta_i = X_{1,i} - X_{0,i}$.

Now assume that we only observe $(Z_i,X_{Z_i,i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$. In other words, for each $i$, we observe either $X_{0,i}$ or $X_{1,i}$, but not both. We know which one we have observed but we don't have access to the other.

Based on this information, we can estimate the expected value of $\Delta$ by computing
$$\frac{1}{\#\{i:Z_i=1\}}\sum_{i:Z_i=1}X_{1,i} - \frac{1}{\#\{i:Z_i=0\}}\sum_{i:Z_i=0}X_{0,i}.$$

However, I want to obtain a measure of dispersion of the distribution of $\Delta$, e.g. by estimating its variance. I'm not sure how to do this, and I'm not even sure this is possible because we have no way to assess the dependence relationship between $X_0$ and $X_1$, as we never observe both of them. Any idea or related literature?

Comment: The dependence relationship among the $X_i$ isn't relevant here.  Part of the problem is the overly elaborate notation: for instance, $Y$ is superfluous.  Just use the [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: I removed any mention to $Y$. I don't understand how to use the law of total variance here. What would be an estimator of $\mathbb{V}(\Delta)$ based on the data $(Z_i, X_{Z_i, i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$?

Comment: Condition on $Z.$

Comment: $Z$ is independent from the other variables.

Comment: Maybe: but *what you observe* is obviously not independent of $Z,$ and that's what matters.

Answer (score 4):

The comment thread suggests that **one insightful way to frame this problem is to distinguish the underlying random variables from what is observed.**  Let's begin, then, by doing exactly that.

We will model the sample by means of the bivariate random variable $(X_0,X_1)$ in the usual way, by supposing the observations are associated with a sequence of *iid* versions of this variable $(X_{0i},X_{1i}),$  $i=1,2,\ldots,n.$  The observations are determined independently by parallel *iid* sequence of a third variable $Z$.  Thus, what is observed is a sequence

$$Y_i = (1-Z_i) X_{0i} + Z_iX_{1i}.$$

The equations

$$Z_i Y_i = Z_i X_{1i}$$

and

$$(1-Z_i)Y_i = (1-Z_i) X_{0i}$$

enable us to express the estimator of the mean of $X_0-X_1$ in the question as

$$\widehat{E[\Delta]} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i) Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i)} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}.$$

(In order for this to be well defined, we must understand either of these fractions to equal zero whenever its denominator is zero.)

**Let's begin by computing the expected value of this estimator *conditional on the $Z_i.$***  Writing $\mathbf{Z}=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n),$

$$E\left[\widehat{E[\Delta]}\mid \mathbf{Z}\right] = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i) \mu_0}{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i)} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \mu_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}=\mu_0-\mu_1,$$

as we would hope.  Similarly, because all the $X_{0i}$ are uncorrelated with all the $X_{1j},$ its conditional variance is

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{E[\Delta]}\mid \mathbf{Z}\right) &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i) \sigma_0^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i)\right)^2} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\sigma_1^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\right)^2} \\
&= \sigma_0^2\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i)} + \sigma_1^2\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}
\end{aligned} \tag{*}$$

(because $Z_i^2 = Z_i$ and $(1-Z_i)^2 = 1-Z_i$).

The [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) (which follows, upon applying a little algebra, from the standard formulas for variance) asserts

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{E[\Delta]}\right) = E\left[\operatorname{Var}(\widehat{E[\Delta]}\mid \mathbf{Z})\right] + \operatorname{Var}\left(E\left[\widehat{E[\Delta]}\mid \mathbf{Z}\right]\right)
\end{aligned}.$$

The second term is the variance of constant and so drops out.  Evaluating the first term requires us to compute the expectations of the fractions in $(*).$  There is no closed form, but the values can be exactly calculated for small to medium $n$ because $\sum Z_i$ has a Binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$ and $\sum (1-Z_i)$ has a truncated Binomial distribution with parameters $n,1-p.$  Thus, bearing in mind the fraction is treated as $0$ when all the $Z_i$ are $0,$

$$E\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}\right] = 0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^k = \int_0^1 \frac{(1 - (1-x)p)^n - (1-p)^n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

The integral is useful for computations when $np$ is small to medium.  Otherwise, the Normal approximation to the Binomial distribution ($np$ and $n(1-p)$ are large) gives

$$E\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}\right] \approx \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

where $\phi$ is the standard Normal density.

By analyzing either integral it's easy to see that to first order this expectation equals the reciprocal of the expectation of the denominator, or $1/(np).$

The calculation involving the $1-Z_i$ is identical but with $p$ replaced by $1-p.$  Thus, to first order, **the following formula gives a reasonable answer to the question:**

> $$\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{E[\Delta]}\right) \approx \frac{\sigma_0^2}{(1-p)n} + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{pn}.$$

If necessary (for small $n$ or extreme values of $p$) it can be improved using either of the two exact formulas (binomial sum and integral).

You can, of course, estimate $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$ separately from the data for which $Z_i=0$ and $Z_i=1,$ respectively.